# Kable and pandoc.table takes only the first six rows

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown, pander

I'm trying to build a table either using `pandoc.table` or `kable` and have problems getting them to print all 10 rows in my table, atm they both only prints the first six. While I moved to write the table manually, which works, it would be nice to know what's wrong with my code. I haven't seen anything to suggest that 6 rows are the limit, so my code should be workning? Anyone know  why it doesn't? If I subset the dt I can print the last 4 as well so maybe 6 rows are a limit. Code below:

```
library("data.table")
library("knitr")
library("pander")

count.mark <- 35

dt.tbl1 <- data.table(Var = c("Geo", "A", "A",
                              "Cust", "A", 
                              "Ins", "A",
                              "Vei", "A",
                              "Brand"),
                      RangeR = c("A1", "S1", "T1",
                                 "Com", "Pri", 
                                 "T", "B",
                                 "Pa", "Pe",
                                 paste("A1 - A99 (",
                                       count.mark, ")", sep="")
                                 )
                      )
pandoc.table(head(dt.tbl1), justify = c("left", "centre"))
kable(head(dt.tbl1), justify = c("left", "centre"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you're using `head(dt.tbl1)`, which by default shows the first six rows.  You should just do, e.g.

```
pandoc.table(dt.tbl1, justify = c("left", "centre"))
```